# Why does the Prism classifier in weka keep on returning NaN values for my dataset?

Tags: weka

I was just wondering I am using the Prism classifier in weka for my dataset, all of my other classifiers work such as decision tree and rule induction and doesn't return any NaN values. However, when I am trying to implement the Prism classifier it works for most of the instances but for a small number of instances I keep on getting NaN values just wondering if there are any pointers that people could point out on how NaN values come when using the Prism Classifier.

Answer (score 0):

PRISM works only on nominal data sets and on data sets without any missing values. Perhaps you might want to check that in your training data set.